# Get the raw query from executemany(sql, params) django/postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

How do I get the raw query from `cursor.executemany(sql, params)` ?

I'm running a query that doesn't work, and I would like to see the query after it's been formated by the cursor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to turn on [`django.db.backends` logging extension](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#django-db-backends):

> Messages relating to the interaction of code with the database. For
>   example, every application-level SQL statement executed by a request
>   is logged at the DEBUG level to this logger.

One of the advantages is that you don't need to make any changes to the code - just to the `settings.py` configration. A good idea would be to have it turned on during development.